# Why does the compiler not deduce captures relationships in generics?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Imagine an interface like this

```
public interface MessageParameter<T> {

  public List<T> unmarshal(byte[] array);
  public int getLength(List<T> values);

}
```

and a consumer of that interface

```
public class GenericUser {

  List<MessageParameter<?>> payload = new ArrayList<>();

  public void run() {
     byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 1, 2 };

     for (MessageParameter<?> element : payload) {
        element.getLength(element.unmarshal(byteArray)); //compiler error
     }
  }
}
```

The compiler gives an error

```
 The method getLength(List<capture#1-of ?>) in the type MessageParameter<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#2-of ?>)
```

Clearly since I am using `element` in both method calls, the type of both is the same and it should be allowed. Another way to ask the same question, why is the compiler creating `capture#2`?? why can't it deduce that they are logically both the same `capture`?

Am I missing something? is there a counter-example where this code would throw a runtime exception??

My main question is not how to fix the code (although that would be interesting as well, my current solution is to use `Object` instead of `?`), but **what is the logical reason for this error?** It looks to me like a shortcoming on the implementation of the compiler more than a logical limitation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that the compiler is not that smart to accept that the runtime type corresponding to `?` is the same because it does not care that your one-line expression involves the same `element`:

```
element.getLength(element.unmarshal(byteArray));
```

is semantically similar to:

```
List<?> unmarshalledList = element.unmarshal(byteArray);
element.getLength(unmarshalledList);
```

In this case, it is not so obvious that the list `unmarshalledList` would surely have to have the same "any-type" as the one expected by `getLength()`. The above are two separate statements (even though they're contiguous). Imagine that they're not contiguous. You may have something like:

```
MessageParameter<?> otherElement = getOtherElement();
for (MessageParameter<?> element : payload) {
    List<?> unmarshalledList = element.unmarshal(byteArray);
    // unmarshalledList can be re-assigned from another parameterized type
    unmarshalledList = otherElement.unmarshal(byteArray);
    element.getLength(unmarshalledList);  // error
}
```

In other words, the compiler cannot assume that the variable `unmarshalledList` will retain the same `?` type from `element` when the program reaches the statement invoking `getLength` on the *same* element. It can be re-assigned to a different parameterized type in between.

Comment: The fact that I made it a one-liner was to demonstrate even more the problem, but what I actually have in the code is exactly what you did. I just don't agree that `it is not so obvious`. It is still obvious (since both forms are equivalent) that it should be allowed. In other words, my surprise is not due to the fact that it is one line. Is there a reason why even the two-lines is not allowed?

Comment: @Hilikus `?` is not the same type as `?`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that would explain it. However, if that were true, `List<?> unmarshalled = element.unmarshal(byteArray);` would not compile since the `?` in the for-loop variable would not be the same as the one in the List declaration, but it does

Comment: No. At the time of assignment, the `?` is captured and bound. `unmarshalledList` has the type `List<?>` where `?` is an unknown but fixed type (called `capture#1` by the compiler). At the same time, `element` has the type `MessageParameter<?>` where the `?` is an unknown but fixed type (called `capture#2` by the compiler). These are not compatible. That's what I mean by `?` is not the same type as `?`.

Comment: The example in this answer can be made more obvious if you do `List<?> unmarshalledList = Arrays.asList("not the type expected by the element");` If your `element` was built with some other type, passing it this `List<String>`, which is hidden behind `?`, would break type safety. Since the compiler cannot guarantee the types match, it refuses the assignment (method argument).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis in that case and in the case from @manouti I would understand the error since the compiler would need to create another `capture` since you are assigning something completely new to `unmarshalledList` so `?` might change its meaning. But when you DON'T reassign, why would you need a different capture? why does the compiler create a new one?

Comment: @hilikus So that's the thing: where do you (the compiler) stop? Some cases it can, some cases it can't. Handling both probably adds tons of complexity.

Comment: @Hilikus Even in the one-line statement, I guess there are two different captures seen by the compiler. As Sotirios said, `element`'s type argument is bound to a different capture than the return value of `element.unmarshal(byteArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misinterpreting the meaning of `?` in a generic. That symbol is known as the wildcard; and it refers to a truly unknown type. This is different from your current effort, in which it would literally be better to use `Object`, as your types are not completely unknown—you know that they both implement `Object` and can reference them as such. (`? extends Object` might be better in some places).

As to the reason why `?` is not synonymous with `Object`, remember that primitives do not inherit from `Object`, but may be referenced with the wildcard. Therefore, after type erasure, your program cannot be certain that the two wildcards are referring to compatible entities; unless you explicitly tell it as much.

Comment: I know `?` is not synonymous to `Object`. My point is that even if it is `unknown` as it is referred by Oracle, you can still know that it is the same in two places. Would you say that x+x = 2*x is false in math because x is "truly unknown"? you have no idea what x is, but you can still make deductions with it, assuming that x is the same everywhere it's used. i.e. you can't have 2+3 = 2*99 since x was not consistently replaced. In my code that `?` can be deduced to be the same